# Tkinter I/O Events

Tags: python, tkinter, event-handling

I'm new to Python as well as event-driven/GUI programming in general. As far as I can tell, all the event choices are things like mouse clicks and key presses.

I've written a set of functions in a separate library that read from an I2C device (on Raspberry Pi). The functions return -1 if nothing is read. So basically, I want to loop, calling the read function each time, until something besides -1 is returned.

My first instinct was to write something like:

```
readResult = -1
while (readResult == -1):
    readResult = IO.read()
changeGUI()
```

This doesn't seem to work though in the tkinter structure. I get how to make a function get called on a button press, but I don't know how to do a custom event.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go with this -- you could give up using Tkinter's `mainloop()`, and build your own event loop that polled for both types of events. Or, you could spawn a separate thread to monitor `IO`. Or, you could use the `after()` method from Tkinter.

For the first two cases, if `IO.read()` returns immediately, whether or not there's a result, then you probably want to throw a `time.sleep()` call in the loop, to avoid hogging the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

If your call to `IO.read()` doesn't block, and doesn't take very long, it's very easy to set up a loop to poll the device every few milliseconds. All you need to do is something like this:

```
def read_one_result():
    readResult = IO.read()
    if readResult != -1:
        changeGUI()
    root.after(100, read_one_result)
```

This will read one result, update the GUI if anything was read, and the schedule itself to run again in 100ms.